# Information regarding SQL

Tags: sql

I have a numbers of tables in the database and i have columns name as "Name", "Roll_No", "Age" and I want to find out the particular information "123456789" which is belongs to "Roll_No" column but I don't know the information is coming from one of the tables in the database, Now i need to find the table name from where this columns value is coming ?

Please Suggest.

Comment: specify more your question. create example tables (with example content) and what should output look like. so far I do not have idea what are you asking

Comment: So what is your query?

Comment: I have 3 nos of table naming as "A" "B" "C" containing columns heading as "Name", "Roll_No", "Age" and I want to locate a record referencing from Roll_No columns, but I don't know the desire record located in which table. I need a SQL command which will output the information of the desire column along with respective table name.